Klaviyo/GTM Tracking variables
I have the below tag which triggers on a page view which works fine. I'm trying to add an extra line of text (variable) to appear next to the 'checkout viewed' metric which is the '{{dlv - category}}' I've added in.
The variable stores fine as I can get it to load as a custom property but I would prefer it to be in the same text as checkout viewed. Is this possible? Is this the correct way to go about it?
https://imgur.com/a/eb6vwBN - Is where I want the variable to appear as text
`<script
  async type="text/javascript"
  src="//static.klaviyo.com/onsite/js/klaviyo.js?company_id=xxxxxx"
></script>

<script>
    var _learnq = _learnq || [];
    _learnq.push(['track', 'checkout viewed', '{{dlv - category}}']);
</script>`

Tried to use the variable as a custom property in Klaviyo which works.

you forgot to include the image?

Thanks BNazaruk. See at https://imgur.com/a/eb6vwBN

Ok, looks like you're looking at the result in Klaviyo. I'm not familiar with Klaviyo, so I don't know if it will like it when checkout viewed has category in it, but hey, you can definitely do that in GTM. Here:
    _learnq.push(['track', 'checkout viewed {{dlv - category}}']);

Is that what you wanted to achieve?

Thanks BNzarauk, that's exactly right. I was just separating them rather than combining.
